# codename1: add external jar "dropbox-core-sdk-3.0.10.jar (IntelliJ)"

Tags: intellij-idea, mobile, dropbox

My mobile app has to upload .csv files and ".jpeg" files to a dropbox account.

I use IntelliJ IDE.

In a standalone Java app I am able to use the dropbox APIs by adding the external jars "dropbox-core-sdk-3.0.10.jar" and "jackson-core-2.7.4.jar".

How can I include these jars in codename1 mobile app that I am developing on IntelliJ IDE?

Thank you

Comment: What mobile app do you develop? Do you use Gradle?

Comment: I would like to make a cross-platform mobile app (android and ios). I don't use gradle. My "ant" build fails. Thanks.